# file_get_contents: get full response even on error

Tags: php, error-handling, file-get-contents

Is it possible to make `file_get_contents` show me the actual response even if an error occurs?

It is difficult to debug otherwise. For instance, say you have the following code:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
$data = array();

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

This shows me NULL for the result and the HTTP headers, but I want to get the actual message Twitter sends back (should be something like `Failed to validate oauth signature and token`), which is what you get if you try to load [`https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token`](https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token) in your browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a very simple switch for the context. just add this line to options:

```
'ignore_errors' => true
```

so you will get

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
    'ignore_errors' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: Awesome, I was hoping there was some sort of switch like this.